# Range arrays with custom step-size in Bourne shells

Tags: bash, zsh, array

Say I want to create a range array of integers in a shell such that the array:

- Starts in `$START_VALUE`
- Ends in `$END_VALUE`
- Elements are `$STEP_SIZE` apart, starting from `$START_VALUE`.

For anyone familiar with Python, I am effectively seeking the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) counterpart in Bourne shells, and specifically in Zsh.

Are there any shell built-ins that help here?

---

Note: Python's `range` function supports increasing and decreasing range arrays  (i.e. where `$START_VALUE` is either greater or smaller than `$END_VALUE`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in bash, [in zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion), this works:

```
printf '%s ' {2..23..3}; echo
```

As this also work:

```
set   -- {2..23..3}
for   i
do    echo "$i"
done
```

As this:

```
set   -- {2..23..3}
for i; do
      echo "$i"
done
```

As this:

```
for i in {0..20..2}
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

What works in zsh but not in bash is ranges with variables:

```
a=2 b=23 c=3
set   -- {$a..$b..$c}
for   i
do    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I assign this array to a variable? I tried the following with no luck: (1) `array=$({2..23..3})`, (2) `vble={2..23..3}`.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina In the first, You are using an additional `$` that is not needed. This works: (1)`array=({2..23..3})` and to see it: `printf '%s ' "${array[@]}"`. The second is missing a transformation to an string: (2)`vble="$(echo {2..23..3})"`, and then `echo "$vble"` as is usual.

Answer (score 1):

In bash and zsh you can use {START..STOP..INCREMENT} and it works as expected when START < STOP.  For example,

```
 for i in {0..20..2}
 do
      echo $i
 done
```

prints out 0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 20.
In bash you can also do "backward" ranges by changing it to {20..0..-2} which would print 20, 18, 16, ..., 2, 0.  This however doesn't work for zsh.

A method that works for both bash and zsh is to use seq.

```
for i in `seq 20 -2 0`;
do
    echo $i
done
```

prints out 20, 18, 16, ..., 0 (in both bash and zsh).  The format here is FIRST, STEP, LAST (and the STEP is optional, if left out, it becomes 1).

Comment: While `{0..20}` comes from zsh, AFAIK, `{0..20..2}` comes from `ksh93`. All 3 (zsh, ksh93, bash) implementations are different on several aspects. For zsh you want `{0..20..-2}` or `{20..0..2}` for backward ranges. Note that the `seq` method depends on the current value of IFS (and needs GNU `seq`).